# Does CKAN log the URL click

Tags: file, logging, tracking, ckan

Does anyone know if I can log the URL file click in CKAN?  Such as if the user clicks the CSV file on the Dataset item.  My manager wants to log clicks to the file.  As it can be located anywhere in the world, I assume this is not logged by default. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this with [ckanext-googleanalytics](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-googleanalytics). It's definitely possible to track click events with google analytics (or any other sufficiently good analytics solution), or your own custom javascript.

The challenge is when people use the CKAN API, or download the link directly without clicking on it. The only way to track that would be to have all your resources stored somewhere you control, so you can track the downloads via the logs on your webserver.